# Glyphicons with Objective C?

Tags: ios, glyphicons

How can I use the glyphicons for iOS ? I cant't find any tutorials. Can anyone explain the steps to be taken and the code to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use glyphicons here like we used in the web.. In iOS, you need to save those as images - png, jpg etc. and then use

First you need to download icons, and then add them to your Images.xcassets as shown in the image below:

[image]

Then drag an UIImageView in the ViewControler:

[image]

Select the UIImageView and then click on the **Show Attributes Inspector** icon at the top right and type the name of icon in the Image textfield under ImageView, in my case the name is **icon1**, and that's it your icon will be added in the imageView -

[image]

Comment: Then why does it say "Icons are designed primarily for toolbars and navigation bars in OS X and iOS apps and other Apple devices"
on http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: Hi, it is written there, but by that, I think they mean those icons are similar like predefined ios icons, just download those and no need to resize and crop, just add to your xcode project and use..

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion !